# Arch linux: Screenshot software cannot save to clipboard

Tags: arch-linux, i3, clipboard, x-server, screenshot

I am trying to use `xfce-screenshooter` to take screenshot and save it to clipboard. Like this:

```
xfce4-screenshooter --region --clipboard
```

but when I try to paste it, there is no image. Thought it was caused by xfce-screenshooter itself. But I tried also `flameshot`, `lightscreen` and `gnome-screenshot` and all of them have same problem.

How can I diagnose and fix this problem ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this counts as a solution since it seems like a bit of a workaround. However, it worked for me.

Instead of using `xfce4-screenshooter`'s clipboard option directly, use a clipboard manager like `xclip`.

For example:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -rs /dev/stdout | xclip -selection clipboard -type image/png
```

At that point I think I would prefer to use `maim`, since usage like this is specifically outlined by its man page

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is now outdated, due to -type option being replaced with -t. 
Now, the command is:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -rs /dev/stdout | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```